# Show that $\frac{3}{8}\le\int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx\le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that $\displaystyle\frac{3}{8}\le\int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx\le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ without calculating the integral.

This is an exercise for training the use of mean value theorem for integral.

I tried to apply it in different ways, but the bounds I get are worst that those I need:

- A direct application does not work
- I also tried to bound first the function and then apply the thorem, but also failed.

I tried to split the interval and apply the Mean value theorem (in fact, is the same that take upper and lower Riemann sums).

Using MATHEMATICA, We need to split the interval in 3 parts (with equal length), to get (something better than) the upper bound; and we need to split the interval in 8 parts to get (something better than) the lower bound.

Now I conjecture there's some mistake/misprint in the original exercise.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: I just want to confirm that a direct application of the mean value theorem does not give the estimates. However, the estimates are true. Could it be that you have some other tool except the mean value theorem?

Comment: Maybe, but probably something easier.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\frac{(1-2x)}{(1-x)^{3/2}(1+x)^{5/2}}$$
so the integrand function is convex over $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. That implies (see [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality)):
$$\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{2}\leq\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)\,dx \leq \frac{f(0)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4}\tag{1}$$
or:
$$\color{red}{0.387}\ldots=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\leq\color{red}{ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\,dx} \leq \frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\color{red}{0.394}\ldots\tag{2}$$
that is way stronger that what was asked to prove.

Comment: Does this solution use the mean value theorem for integrals?

Comment: @QuinnCulver: (1) is an instance of the mean value theorem for convex functions.